# Modal - content is getting out of modal on smaller monitors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I've downloaded a free modal plugin called **blockUI**, and used it as my image uploading modal.

So far i've designed, positioned everything, but I have one problem:

When I make my browser screen smaller, OR go on iphone, or go on my other screen, some content gets out of the modal

**See example here:**

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/0c6701255d875353af814dc1ae2ead58.png))</sub>

**See LIVE example of the website to test on your screen:**

https://argonite.net/img/

Why is this happening? I have set `min-width`, the modal should automatically ***resize*** the background and let the content in.

Information:

`.file_bg` Each file will be stored in file_bg, it's like a block that will hold image preview, progress bar, and more.

`#button_start` - the progress bar

`#button_remove` - #button_link - Remove / Copy to clipboard icons

CSS File:

http://pastebin.com/QwF4Vj3B

JS file:

http://pastebin.com/xWt6bC32

**Why is it doing that?**

Comment: reduce width or margin-left from `.loading_start` CSS class will fix the out size window issue.

Comment: You can see the same here in SO, when uploading images in firefox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **div.blockUI blockMsg blockPage** change min-width:35%; to width:35% and add min-width with a fixed pixel value (520px seems to be good in your case). That should do the trick. For mobile, you can use @media queries to apply different values for width and min-width.

```
div.blockUI blockMsg blockPage {
width:35%;
min-width:520px;}
```

Comment: VERY nice, you saved my time. Thanks a lot! +1 for mobile

Comment: No problem :) And in case you're new to @media queries: [Link](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)